# Bad accuracy with pocketsphinx and error integrating spanish dictioraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I want a program that recognize certain words. I have this code, that works well using recognize_google and I can change it easily to spanish. I want to use recognize_sphinx beacuse it´s free and works offline but it doesn´t reconize what Im saying in english, not even close. 
And I don´t know how to integrate the spanish library that I can download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish/

How can I make it work well in english and how can I integrate the spanish dictionaries?

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)   
    while True:
         audio = r.listen(source)
         # recognize speech using Sphinx
         try:
             print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
          except sr.UnknownValueError:
              print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
          except sr.RequestError as e:
             print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: This can helps you : https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialtuning/